# CoreData - Computed Property in Background Thread

Tags: core-data

I am fetching about 2500 stars from `CoreData` to use in constructing a star map and would like to do most of the math for computing coordinates and such in a background thread for obvious reasons. My question is, since I have to pass the `CoreData` objects back to the main thread as `NSManagedObjectID`s, how would you go about computing say, a set of cartesian coordinates in a background thread and (preferably) set those coordinates in the `NSManagedObject` subclass?

For what it's worth, here is a snippet of the code I'm using to fetch from CoreData and pass to the main thread:

```
// Context and Model
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.dataProvider newManagedObjectContext];
NSManagedObjectModel *model = [self.dataProvider sharedManagedObjectModel];

// Fetch the stars
NSArray *stars = [SkyObject getSkyObjectsBetweenMinCoords:minCoords 
                                                maxCoords:maxCoords 
                                                   minMag:self.minimumMagnitude 
                                                   maxMag:self.maximumMagnitude 
                                                    model:model 
                                                  context:context];

NSMutableArray *starIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Add the star's objectID to the set
for (SkyObject *star in stars) {
    [starIDs addObject:star.objectID];
}

// Pass objects across thread boundaries
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateLocalContextWithObjectIDs:) withObject:starIDs waitUntilDone:YES];

// Release retained memory
[starIDs release];
[context release];
```

Answer (score 1):

i can tell from your question and code this is way above my head.  but what about GCD.  its what im using for a repeated keep alive being sent via tcp/ip.  anyways hope it helps
http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2010/06/27/a-simple-job-queue-with-grand-central-dispatch/

Answer (score 0):

You normally don't "pass the CoreData objects back to the main thread as NSManagedObjectIDs" but instead you would perform all your operations setting up the managed objects with a context running on the background thread and then when you are done, you would merge the foreground context with the background context.

Passing managedObjectIDs works of course but its a slow way to go about it especially if you have thousands of objects to process. It also doesn't update the entire object graph like a merge does.

Comment: `you would merge the foreground context with the background context` - Could you point me to an example of this?

Comment: See Core Data Programming Guide: Track Changes in Other Threads Using Notifications at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW5

Comment: The same article says the opposite of what your answer says.  `To “pass” a managed object from one context another across thread boundaries, you either: Pass its object ID (objectID) and use objectWithID: or existingObjectWithID:error: on the receiving managed object context.` etc...